# How do I find the position of first number in a string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, search, find, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find the position of the first number in a string (cell E4) in Google Sheets

I've tried:

```
=FINDB("\D+";E4)
=FINDB("[0-9]";E4)
=FINDB("[0-9]+";E4)
```

But none of these have worked

An example could be "I am 23 year old" then the position of the first number would be 6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=FINDB(REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "\d"); A1)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `REGEXEXTRACT` with `^\D*` pattern to extract all non-digit chars at the start of the string (if any, `*` means *0 or more occurrences*) and then get the length of the resulting string to find the zero-based index of the digit char (or add `1` for a one-based index):

```
=LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^\D*"))
=LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^\D*"))+1
```

Test:

[image]